# StreamWriter.Write is not writing all the data

Tags: c#, textwriter

I am trying to  create a text file by a loop data .each loop data i have send to another method and creating the text file as blow .

```cs
//another method each and every for loop time this method will run.
public void  TextFileGen1(string pdate, string oPno, string supCode, string supName, string cur, string docTotal, string glAct, string glName, string pType, string jRemark, string rmk)
{
    if (pType == "CEFT")
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"E:\filename.txt", true))
        {
            file.Write(pdate, oPno, supCode);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"E:\DFCC\filename.txt", true))
        {
            file.Write(pdate, oPno, supCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Current output is like this:

```
20201228 20201229
```

But I expected this output:

```
20201229,hgfd,gfd
20201228,yhgtfr,hygtfr
```

Please could anyone tell me how to do it.

Comment: The code is very unclear. What is in the output and what is not in the output, other than the missing commas?

Comment: Basically, your call to `StreamWriter.Write` doesn't do what you expect it to. In the overload you're using, the first parameter is expected to be a format string, and the other parameters are expected to be arguments for that format string.

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be using the Write function correctly.

I think the call you want is:

```
file.Write("{0},{1},{2}", pdate, oPno, supCode);
```

The first argument is the 'format string' and its followed by the arguments.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.write?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
file.Write(pdate, oPno, supCode);
```

to:

```
file.WriteLine(pdate + "," + oPno + "," + supCode);
```